# Independent random variables $(X_i)$ have the same law, then $(X_i,\sum X_i ) $ have the same law for any $i$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_i)$ be sequence of real independent r.v.'s and having the same law. If we let $X=\sum X_i$, how can one show that $(X_i, X)$ have the same law for any $i$. In this case $(X_i, X)$ is a random vector.
(I think we can also say if $(X_i, X )$ have the same law then every $X_i$ have the same law. But no idea how to prove this too). Since $X$ and $X_i$ are not independent we can't do the usual trick to seperate the laws.

Comment: What is your definition of $\sum X_i$?

Comment: just sum of them, ie $\sum X_i = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + .... $. Not sure if its correct for infinite sum but i'm guessing that this is true for finite sum. @drhab

Comment: I thought so, but then for infinite sum $X$ is not properly defined. There might exist $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i(\omega)$ has no limit.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to prove this for the finite case ?

Comment: If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are iid then $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $(X_{\sigma(1)},\dots,X_{\sigma(n)})$ have the same law for every permutation $\sigma$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. This with $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_{\sigma(i)}$. That implies that $(X_1,X)$ and $(X_{\sigma(1)},X)$ have the same law.